# Remove `Terminal - ` from xfce4-terminal's window title

Tags: window, titlebar, xfce4-terminal

Using xfce4-terminal, if I type:

```
PS1="\[\e]0;\w\a\]> "
```

I get as expected `>` as my prompt, and the current working directory shows up in the window title. But instead of just being `~/Documents`, the window's title is `Terminal - ~/Documents`.

[image: Screenshot of xfce4-terminal with <code>Terminal - ~/Documents</code> in the window's title]

How can completely customize xfce4-terminal's window title, and get rid of the `Terminal -` part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XFCE Terminal's *Preferences*, are options to control the title:

[image]

Change the *Dynamically-set title* to *Replaces initial title*.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the border of the terminal on the general tab of the terminal preference or add `--hide-borders` option on terminal as following:

```
xfce4-terminal --disable-borders
```

If you want to remove all decorations of xfce4 terminal like rxvt style

```
xfce4-terminal --hide-menubar --hide-borders --hide-toolbar
```